# Valores de tabla pivote con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy usando laravel 5.5, tengo un modelo Member y un modelo Team, hice la relación belongsToMany correctamente. El problema es que en la tabla pivote de esa relación hay varios datos a los que necesito acceder, por ejemplo los campos seasonGames, seasonWins y personalRating, y no he podido acceder a ellos, de pronto estoy haciendo mal las cosas, lo intenté agregando los campos con el metodo withPivot pero no logro rescatar los datos.

hice éste metodo en el modelo Member:

```
public function teams(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team','team_member','teamId','guid')->withPivot(['seasonGames', 'seasonWins', 'personalRating']);
}
```

pero ahora que debo hacer para acceder a esos datos? intenté usando 
$member->pivot como muestra la documentacion pero solo contiene los indices de las tablas y nada más :/

EDITADO:
Las tablas y los campos que uso son éstas

members:

- guid  PK
- name

teams:

- teamId PK
- name
- type
- rating
- seasonGames
- seasonWins

member_team:

- teamId (PK de teams)
- guid (PK de members)
- seasonGames
- seasonWins
- personalRating

Los modelos son:

```
    class Member extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'guid';

        public function teams(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team','team_member','teamId','guid')->withPivot(['seasonGames', 'seasonWins', 'personalRating']);
}
    }


    class Team extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "teamId";

    public function members(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member','team_member','teamId','guid');
}
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código de ambos modelos, así como las migraciones para ver las tres tablas involucradas.

Comment: listo, he añadido los modelos y los campos de las tablas involucrados, como la base de datos ya estaba creada no estoy usando migraciones.

Comment: No se muestran en un atributo `pivot`? ejemplo: `$member->teams[0]->pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir una relación con las llaves que tienes en las distintas tablas, tendrías que utilizar buena parte de los argumentos de `belongsToMany`.

Estos son dichos argumentos:

```
public function belongsToMany(
    $related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
        $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
```

Siendo:

- `$parentKey` la llave del modelo actual
- `$relatedKey` la llave del modelo relacionado

---

En el caso del modelo Member sería:

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'member_team', 'guid', 'teamId', 'guid', 'teamId')
->withPivot(['seasonGames', 'seasonWins', 'personalRating']);
}
```

Sin embargo, si tienes el primary Key definido en el modelo teniendo en cuenta que no es `'id'`, no serían necesarios los dos últimos argumentos:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'guid';
```

---

En cuanto al modelo Team sería algo similar, pero "invertido":

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member', 'member_team', 'teamId', 'guid', 'teamId', 'guid')
->withPivot(['seasonGames', 'seasonWins', 'personalRating']);
}
```

Y también se puede definir la llave personalizada:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'teamId';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Shaz, me fue muy util tu respuesta para darme cuenta del error.

Comment: Si la respuesta fue útil, puedes aceptarla.

Comment: Listo compa, no había visto esa cosa xd

Answer (score 0):

he podido solucionarlo, estaba utilizando al revés la relación, nose si esté correcta la respuesta, pero ha funcionado.

El modelo Member en su atributo pivot solo contenía los ids de la relación, y por obvias razones, no me di cuenta, el modelo Team solo tomaba esos valores por la forma en que definí el método de la relación:

```
    public function members(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member','team_member','teamId','guid');

    }
```

Simplemente añadí los campos al método correcto de ésta forma:

```
public function members(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member','team_member','teamId','guid')->withPivot(['seasonGames', 'seasonWins', 'personalRating']);

}
```

De esa forma ha retornado el modelo con el pivote junto a los campos solicitados. Para acceder a ellos solo hice lo siguiente en el modelo Member:

```
public function getSeastonGames(){

    return $this->pivot->seasonGames;
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda muchachos